# Is it allowed to do like this with foreach?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have this code that i made and i m not really sure if its the correct way.
I get error:

> ```
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
> ```

i make this array from xmldata from my mysql database

```
$array_xml = array();
$array_xml = xml2array($row['xmlData']);

$moneyDetails = array();
$moneyDetails = $array_xml['some1']['some2']['some3']['some4']['some5']['some6']['some7']['some8']['some9'];


foreach($moneyDetails->ContributionData AS $ContributionData){
    $ContributorCode = $ContributionData->ContributorCode;

    echo $ContributorCode;

}
```

Comment: Is `$moneyDetails->ContributionData` an array? The error seems to suggest it's not. `var_dump` can tell you

Comment: `$moneyDetails->ContributionData` looks like that's not an array

Comment: If you get _Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()_ the only thing you can be sure of is that _It is not the correct way_ PHP does not make this stuff up because it get bored you know

Comment: @Machavity i get back array(1) {
  ["ContributionData"]=>
  array(13) {
    [0]=>
    array(7) {
      ["ContributorCode"]=> .. << part of it

Comment: Post that (all) in your question to help us out a bit here

Comment: @RiggsFolly ok that made my error go away

Comment: Please double check the documentation on object arrays & normal arrays. It'll clear things up

Comment: Thanks guys problem solved thanks @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $moneyDetails is an array then try

```
foreach($moneyDetails['ContributionData'] as $ContributionData)
```

You are addressing it like it was an Object